# Find File Path and Read the FIle

Tags: android, file, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I know that the file is in `Device Storage/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents` and I want to read it (in fact there are many files there and I want to read any of them).

I am using Intent to get all pdf files.

In onActivityResult... `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {` I am doing:

```
String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();

                    FilePath = FilePath.substring(FilePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).trim();

                    String path = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
                    String alternatePath = "Device Storage\\WhatsApp\\Media\\WhatsApp Documents";
                    File file = new File( alternatePath+ "\\" + FilePath);
```

Next I am doing all the `FileInputStream` etc stuff. But for some reason, it is giving filenotfound exception.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

P.S. the startactivityforresult part:

```
savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE); 

            }
        });
```

Comment: "In onActivityResult" -- what is your `startActivityForResult()` call that triggers this `onActivityResult()` callback?

Comment: Please check the updated code

Comment: Get of the `File` and `FileInputStream` stuff. Simply call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on the content.